# selenium c# how to set values to Span and hidden span text

Tags: c#, selenium

i am trying to send values to tag-text using c# selenium. tried different scenarios but could not. can any one help me?

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="darkTag">
        <div class="contents">
            <span class="tag-text">Tamil</span>
            <div class="tag-remove">x</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tag-bg" style="background: rgb(255, 87, 51);"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share the code that you have tried and the error message. Do you see an input field when click on span?

Comment: @ParthibanKannappan `<span>` tag is visible but what exactly do you mean by _hidden span text_ and which text do you want to set in which tag?